# display component based on a conditional

Tags: angular

I have this field in `app.component.ts`

```
front: boolean = true;
```

And I am displaying this component template in `app.component.html`

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

That works, but I want to display that component (or not) based on the value of `front`, so i tried something like this which does not work:

```
<*ngIf="front" app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `ngIf` after `app-navbar`(component name)

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="front"></app-navbar>
```

Comment: what does the * mean/indicate?

Comment: @HerChip * indicates its [a structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directives).

Answer (score 1):

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="front"></app-navbar>
```

You have to open the tag (with app-nav) and then use the *ngIf